# How do I set different wallpapers in each Virtual Desktop on KDE 5?

Tags: kde, desktop-background, kde5

How can I set different wallpaper in each virtual Desktop on KDE in Kubuntu 16.10 or newer?

Answer (score 1):

16.10 is now end of life, but this applies to current releases as well.

Upstream KDE developers do not currently plan to restore this feature.

See: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=341143

Comment #212 on that bug mentions a 3rd party solution that I cannot vouch for.